# Android Application to Fill out a PDF Form

Tags: android, pdf

I want to design an application for a PDF form just to automate its filling through an Android Application. I want to show the user some forms designed on xml(android application UI) and fill the pdf form with the incoming information. I have the form on PDF i just want to will it with my application and store it. Any suggestions to achieve this task ? cause i am unable to figure it out. Its just programmatically filling out a pdf form with Java on Android

help .....

Comment: Have you searched for libraries for handling pdf files, preferably those which have already been ported to android?

Comment: I came across Quotta something. It requires $$. I want an east solution through a nice SDK .. still looking for help

Comment: I came across iText and that is not supported on Android :s

Comment: Not sure if the following is going to help you (thus it's in comment), but there is a free Android app called Fill and Sign PDF Forms and allows 3rd party app integration.