# Fill PDF Forms and Save Android

Tags: android

I have a editable .pdf file contain multiple forms. I want to open that file, fill the forms and save it. Is there any SDK available for that? I searched but I did not get any satisfactory responses.

I got this links:

- [Android fill PDF form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736384/android-fill-pdf-form)
- [Android Application to Fill out a PDF Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556285/android-application-to-fill-out-a-pdf-form)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509258/display-edit-and-save-pdf-in-android

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Did you have any solution?

Comment: yes, you can do this using iText library.